# DNS Caching for ssh in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: dns, cache

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
A specific domain changed the IP recently. When I do `ping xyz.com` the new IP appears. When I do `ssh xyz.com` it still connects to the old IP.

Is there a specific DNS caching for ssh? How can I flush it?

Comment: It should take about 24 hours for full refresh of the DNS tables. I have had similar problem few months ago.  What is the result of `$ nslookup xyx.com`.

Comment: `nslookup` returns the correct new IP.

Answer (score 1):

It might be `nscd` that does the caching for you in this case.

You can flush `nscd` cache with a restart of the service.

```
$ sudo service nscd restart
```

`nscd` is a name service caching daemon, and several utilities on a system will try use this before going further. All tools using libc for name resolutions.

Comment: I don't have `nscd` installed: it says `nscd: unrecognized service`